# Como criar um Constructor quando há if/else e variáveis externas?

Tags: jquery, funções, construtor

Tenho diversas variáveis como esta, que chamam um Elemento do HTML sempre com o mesmo nome:

```
var $inputFromA = $(".inputFromA");
```

São pelo menos umas 10: `inputFromA`, `inputFromB`, `inputFromC`…

Todas estas variáveis também chamam exatamente a mesma função:

```
$inputFromA.on("input", function () {
  var val = $(this).prop("value");
  if (val < min) {
    val = min;
  } else if (val > to) {
    val = to;
  }
  instance.update({
    from: val
  });
});
```

É possível criar uma função construtora ou classe constante para que eu possa apenas declarar o nome da variável e chamar apenas a classe/função?

Imagino que seria algo como:

```
class InputFrom () {}

var inputFromA = new InputFrom;
```

A minha dificuldade se deve a quantidade de parâmetros que tal função deverá ter. Alguém poderia me dar uma força com isso?

Comment: O que é esse `instance` no código? Por que você quer criar a classe? Sua pergunta não ficou clara; seria bom você a [edit] para torná-la um pouco mais clara.

Comment: Estou trabalhando com Ion.RangeSlider (http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/index.html) e `instance` é requerido para que o slider preencha um `input` com um número.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode relacionar essa função a uma constante ou uma variavel, e depois retornar o resultado dessa função:

```
let ChamaFuncao = $inputFromA.on("input", function () {
  var val = $(this).prop("value");
  if (val < min) {
    val = min;
  } else if (val > to) {
    val = to;
  }
  instance.update({
    from: val
  });
return ChamaFuncao;
});
```

depois daqui é só chamar a função sempre que quiser usar ela.

aqui tem um link explicando bem sobre return: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_return.asp

Comment: Excelente a sua solução, Vitor!! Muito obrigado, amigo! Apenas editei a sua resposta para que o código fique melhor de ser visualizado. Brigadão!